# FreeRTOS in LPC1343

Tags: embedded, freertos, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to config my project to FreeRTOS for LPC1343. But I'm getting the following errors

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY" is undefined C:\Users\IAR Embedded Workbench\FreeRTOS\Source\queue.c 952 


Fatal Error[Pe035]: #error directive: configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY must not be set to 0.  See  C:\Users\IAR Embedded Workbench\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\IAR\ARM_CM3\port.c 82
```

Can you please help me with these errors and also I would like to what are steps that I have to take when I'm config FreeRTOS to my LPC1343.
Thank you

Comment: The first thing to note is that if you are using an LPC1343, then including iolpc1342.h is probably incorrect and conflicts with declarations in iolpc1343.h.  You have to figure out why iolpc1342.h has been included (probably through some chain of nested includes and conditional compilation - most likely you have an inappropriate  processor type macro definition set somewhere.  Quite possibly nothing particular to do with FreeRTOS at all.

Comment: I have solved the first error. I would really like solution for the next 2 errors

Comment: You should then perhaps either remove that first part from your question or post an answer to your own question if the solution is likely to be useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` is not defined when first encountered line 952 of queue.c.

Undefined macros have value zero when explicitly tested for value rather then existence; hence the `#error` directive output.  That is if say `ABC` is undefined then `#if defined ABC` is false but `#if ABC==0` will be true.

`configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` should be defined in FreeRTOSConfig.h as described [here](http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html), and may not be zero.  Be sure to read all the notes on setting this value - there are special considerations for Cortex-M3 ports.

Comment: Yes, I read about it. but I'm still confused what value should be set for each of these,
`configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY `                   
`configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY`          `configMAX_API_CALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY`              For LPC1343

Comment: Setting to a non-zero value will at least allow it to build - not defining it at all is not an option. The value to use however is a different question.  I have not used FreeRTOS, but would be amazed if there were not already an LPC1xxx port from which you could take at least initial working settings.

Answer (score 0):

The values needed are dependent on the microcontroller family.  It is a little tricky, which is why there is an attempt at explaining it here: http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html  You need to know how many interrupt priority bits are implemented (in hardware) on your LPC device, then set the constants to match that.  If you are using a bleeding edge version of FreeRTOS and have configASSERT() defined then it should tell you if you get it wrong.  You can also working it out manually by writing 0xFF into an interrupt priority register, then reading the register value back to see how many of the 8-bits 'stuck'.  As described on the link above, the bits will be the most significant bits, not the least significant bits as might first be expected.